# Filter Condition in Rest API query with passing textbox value

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, office-365, rest

The below mentioned query is correct or not because i am not getting the `textbox` values.
`#txtAFENo`. It is `textbox` id , passing directly the `textbox` value.

```
query.RestQuery = "getbytitle('RFA')/Items?$select=ESI_ProjectSeqNoLookup/Id&$expand=ESI_ProjectSeqNoLookup&$filter=ESI_AFENo/Id eq '#txtAFENo'";
```

Comment: Atish Please reply for this i need a solution urgent.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what programming language you are using.

Assuming JavaScript and jQuery

```
query.RestQuery = "getbytitle('RFA')/Items?$select=ESI_ProjectSeqNoLookup/Id&$expand=ESI_ProjectSeqNoLookup&$filter=ESI_AFENo/Id eq '" + $('#txtAFENo').val() + "'";
```

Comment: ESI_AFENo Type is Hyperlink or Picture whether i have to give ESI_AFENo/Hyperlink or Picture???